# How to link button to a pre-existing "like" icon

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a "like" icon that was created using this tutorial: https://hofmannsven.com/2013/laboratory/wordpress-post-like-system/ which I am using on my homepage and works great.

However, I was wondering if it was possible to link this "like" functionality to a button. I was thinking I might be able to utilize `onClick()` somehow?

Right now, I have the icon sitting absolutely positioned within a button (you can see this by directly hovering over the icon to tell that it is not part of the same button entity), and when you click anywhere inside the button (besides directly on the icon, it doesn't register as a "like").

**Here is the like button:** [image]

**And the page you can use it on:** https://www.uncvrd.co/calmani-grey-tattoo-feat-pearl-andersson/

Here is my button html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default  dig-btn" onclick="">
   <?php echo get_simple_likes_button( get_the_ID() ); ?><span class="dig-text">Dig</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find get_simple_likes_button function and find this line within inside of the function then simply add `<button` around `<a href` and then at the closing part `</a>` add `</button>` looking into your onClick() then going to a header location is just not suggested and is better to use `<a href` to redirect to link.

```
$output = '<span class="sl-wrapper"><a href="' . admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=process_simple_like' . '&post_id=' . $post_id . '&nonce=' . $nonce . '&is_comment=' . $is_comment . '&disabled=true' ) . '" class="sl-button' . $post_id_class . $class . $comment_class . '" data-nonce="' . $nonce . '" data-post-id="' . $post_id . '" data-iscomment="' . $is_comment . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $icon . $count . '</a>' . $loader . '</span>';
```

Comment: thanks for the response, my understanding of toggle was that it displayed the property. Wouldn't I need a different function to take action upon the icon to act as a "click" per-say?

Comment: @JordanLewallen It is still hard to understand what you are trying to say do you perhaps mean the decoration of the button when pressed because in the link you provided it does not show the icon on the button changing

Comment: Basically, I have this "bolt" icon that acts as a "like" feature. When someone clicks on the bolt, it stores the like into the database. I created this using the tutorial I provided. My question is, on this specific page, I would like to use a `<button>` to control the submission of a like, instead of just the icon. Does that help?

Comment: @JordanLewallen so you would like if the button called the php function to run your sql?

Comment: @JordanLewallen changed the answer uptop see if it is what you are looking for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133179/discussion-between-jordan-lewallen-and-jacob-webb).